# Configuring tasks late in Gradle build lifecycle

Tags: gradle

I have a multiproject build. Some of the projects in the build produce test results. One project produces an installer, and I want that project's artifacts to include the test results from all the other projects. I attempted to do that like this (in the project that produces an installer):

```
// Empty test task, so that we can make the gathering of test results here depend on the tests' having
// been run in other projects in the build
task test << {
}

def dependentTestResultsDir = new File( buildDir, 'dependentTestResults' )

task gatherDependentTestResults( type: Zip, dependsOn: test ) {

    project.parent.subprojects.each { subproject ->

        // Find projects in this build which have a testResults configuration
        if( subproject.configurations.find { it.name == 'testResults' } ) {

            // Extract the test results (which are in a zip file) into a directory
            def tmpDir = new File( dependentTestResultsDir, subproject.name )
            subproject.copy {
                from zipTree( subproject.configurations['testResults'].artifacts.files.singleFile )
                into tmpDir
            }
        }
    }

    // Define the output of this task as the contents of that tree
    from dependentTestResultsDir
}
```

The problem is that at the point when this task is configured, the test tasks in the other projects haven't run, so their artifacts don't exist, and I get messages during my build like this:

```
The specified zip file ZIP 'C:\[path to project]\build\distributions\[artifact].zip' does not exist and will be silently ignored. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
```

So I need to do something that will involve the configuration of my task being delayed until the test artifacts have actually been produced. What is the idiomatic way to achieve this?

I seem to need to address questions of this nature quite frequently about Gradle. I think I'm missing something conceptually.

Answer (score 1):

In that instance, you should just be able to make it an action by adding `<<` as in

```
task gatherDependentTestResults( type: Zip, dependsOn: test ) << {
    // your task code here
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me - the task is always considered to be up-to-date.

The task has to be a Zip or similar, because I'm going to use it in an artifacts script block, but if I put my code in an action like that the Zip task doesn't get configured (at least I assume that's what's happening).

Comment: add another task that the zip task depends on and use that task to do the configuration (of the zip task)